# How can I break or continue knockout's arrayforeach?

Tags: knockout.js

This is sample code. I want to break (or continue) knockout's ko.util.arrayForEach.

```
ko.utils.arrayForEach(items, function (item) {
    if (...) break;
    if (...) continue;
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Looks like you can't.  Here's the source of arrayForEach (from [utils.js](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/blob/master/src/utils.js) on the KO GitHub page)

```
arrayForEach: function (array, action) {
    for (var i = 0, j = array.length; i < j; i++)
        action(array[i]);
},
```

**However** Knockout provides `ko.utils.arrayFirst` that will execute a function against each item in our array and return the first item where the function evaluates to true. Similar to the filteredItems computed observable, we can create one that returns the first match from our search field:

```
//identify the first matching item by name
viewModel.firstMatch = ko.computed(function() {
    var search = this.search().toLowerCase();
    if (!search) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return ko.utils.arrayFirst(this.filteredItems(), function(item) {
            return ko.utils.stringStartsWith(item.name().toLowerCase(), search);
        });
    }
}, viewModel);
```

More details can be found here http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/utility-functions-in-knockoutjs.html

Comment: What is the point of initializing `j`? You can just do `i < array.length`.

Comment: @TheMuffinMan The point of j is to possibly save some milliseconds by preventing having to dereference the array during each loop iteration.  See [this StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17989270/javascript-for-loop-performance-storing-array-length-in-a-variable).  From the jsperf referenced in the accepted answer to that question, it looks like on modern browsers it doesn't make much difference.

Comment: see my answer below !!

Answer (score 9):

Seems like `ko.utils.arrayFirst` or `ko.utils.arrayFilter` will fit your needs better then your current approach.

Comment: The requirement is about performance. I want to make multiple things in a loop.

Comment: Use simple loop, it will save you few milliseconds, because in this case you will just run you code and not call sub function that you pass to arrayForEach

Answer (score 1):

Just use **`ko.utils.arrayFirst`** that will execute a function on the `array` and and will **return/break** as soon as the the `function` evaluates to true.

Here is realife **example** that I recently used

```
this.updateElement = function (model) {
    ko.utils.arrayFirst(that.list(), function (m) {
        if (model.formId() === m.formId()) {
            m.description(model.description());
            m.status(model.status());
            m.type(model.type());
        }
    });
}
```

More details can be found here http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/utility-functions-in-knockoutjs.html