# Loop count for loops

Tags: loops, optimization

Does it do any good to have the loop count in a temp variable. Like it does not need to fetch the count value every time through the execution of the loop.

```
var iCount = iArray.length, jCount = jArray.length;
for(var i=0; i<iCount; i++){
  for(var j=0; j<jCount; j++) {
    ...
  }
}
```

The above example shows Arrays but it need not be an Array always it could also be a class like in `myObject.total`.

Comment: Compiler will not have to lookup for length for every iteration

Comment: Possible duplicate of [For-loop performance: storing array length in a variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17989270/for-loop-performance-storing-array-length-in-a-variable)

Answer (score 1):

As commented, compiler will have to lookup for length for every iterations.

**Samples**

---

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
var result=[];

function getLength(){
  console.log('check Length');
  return arr.length
}

for (var a = 0; a < getLength(); a++){
  result.push(arr[a]);
}
```

#### Length saved in temp variable

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
var result=[];

function getLength(){
  console.log('check Length');
  return arr.length
}
var length = getLength()
for (var a = 0; a < length; a++){
  result.push(arr[a]);
}
```

---

Also, if you are manipulating same array, it can cause some issues

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5];

for (var a = 0; a < arr.length; a++){
  console.log(arr.splice(a,1))
}
```

#### Length in temp variable

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5];

var length = arr.length
for (var a = 0; a < length; a++){
  console.log(arr.splice(a,1))
}
```

---