# Why is this way of working with an array not optimal?

Tags: javascript, arrays

My teacher showed us this piece of code at the end of my cs class today and asked us to think about why it was not optimal.

Here is the code:

```
for (var x = 0; x < array.length; x++) {
        console.log(array[x]);
}
```

I can't figure out what's wrong. I think maybe it is better to use a 'forEach' perhaps, but I'm not sure why?

```
Something like this?:

array.forEach(function(element) {
        console.log(element);
});
```

Comment: Not optimal in the sense of too many lines of code or in the sense of being inefficient somehow? Also with `forEach` you can shorten it to `array.forEach(console.log)` however this is just shorter in lines of code, it still does a loop

Comment: There's also an argument that `forEach()` will be internally optimal so the JIT compiler will have less work to do. Furthermore, you have a bug using `x` as the loop variable but `array[i]` for the index; this is impossible to make in the functional case. ;-) On the other hand, you could have a finger-slip and spell `element` as `emelent`, but hopefully you would get a warning about an unused function parameter.

Comment: Well, for one, it's broken. You're using `i` as the index but `x` in the iterator. But "optimal" is heavily context-based - optimal *how*? Faster? Clearer to read? More correct? Safer? Using latest language features? More composable?

Comment: Sorry that was meant to be a x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably just go with:

```
for(const el of array) { /*...*/ }
```

Why is that better? Well, you just need to look at it once, to get that it executes the block `for` every `el of array`. Its much faster to read than:

```
for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  const el = array[i];
  /*...*/
}
```

And as programming languages are mainly there to be easily understandable by humans, you should always try to make the code as readable as possible. And it is also easier to spot bugs in the code if it is more readable, therefore increasing security, maintainability and development time.

Comment: Here is a jsperf I put together for evaluating accessing the array length. [JSPerf Setup](https://jsperf.com/accesing-length-of-array/1). Apologies for commenting here. The original answer where we were discussing this is has now been deleted

Comment: @chirag it crashes chrome on andrpid, so what are the results?

Comment: I am actually a little confused now. My first few trials supported my initial suggestion that accessing the length only once is faster. But when I ran it a few more times, it came out both ways.. Not sure how this result can be variable.. I honestly expected it to be solidly one or the other

Comment: [Related Question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17989270/for-loop-performance-storing-array-length-in-a-variable?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) sheds a little light on this. See the non- accepted answers as well

Comment: @chirag and they all conclude that its not worth caching the length. So my points are still valid

Comment: Yup. From what I understood, it's dependent on the engine and most engines hoist that out of the loop anyway.

Answer (score 0):

By keeping the `for` loop, you could omit the different return value of postfix vs prefix syntax for the [increment operator `++`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Increment_()).

```
x++ // take value, then increment, slower 
++x // increment, take value, faster
```

Answer (score 0):

You should get the length into a variable rather than using it as array.length in the loop. ie. 
`var length = array.length.
for(let i = 0; i < length; i++)`

Comment: Why should this be "better" ?!