# Should I assign the length of array to another variable in for loop?

Tags: javascript

I'm learning Javascript and the for loop here looks exactly the same as in C. What I'm wondering is whether I should assign the length of a string to another variable in the loop. I usually do that in C when looping over a char array so the loop does not have to call `strlen` with each iteration:

```
for (int i = 0, n = strlen(word); i < n; i++)
{
    // code block
}
```

What I see from following tutorials is that a for loop in Javascript is just written without assigning array length of a variable:

```
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    // code block
}
```

Is there any advantage to assigning the length of the array to a variable in Javascript?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No benefit, not as important as in C because `arr.length` is a static property i.e. it is not computed, unlike `strlen` which would compute the length each time it is called.

edit: [see for yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17995000/8378419), its a controversial issue but it seems like accessing the property directly is fastest

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to go back through my code and change them.

Comment: While it is not an accessor property as you say, there is a measurable time difference between accessing `length` from a variable vs. a property, and you also run the risk of getting stuck in an infinite loop if you modify the array within the loop. For these reasons, there are indeed benefits. This is why [the specification](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.foreach) has explicit steps for storing the length in a temporary variable.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts do you have any reference for that measurable time difference? I would like to see

Comment: I had done benchmarks a few years ago and found that it did improve iteration speed. As it turns out, it looks like v8 has now closed the speed gap as you point out since it's a common pattern, though I'd still prefer to cache it in a variable if you plan to modify the array while iterating it.