# Does storing in variables increase performance? And do var, let, const also affect performance?

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, variables

For example, in a node app, using express, instead of using:

`app.listen(3000);`

we use:

```
const port = 3000;
app.listen(port)
```

Will it increase performance, albeit no matter how small?
I heard, for example, it improves performance of loops.

And off-topic: isn't app.listen() function kinda a loop? Or does it use an inbuilt loop?

Also,
does declaring with var, let, or const differ from one another in performance? For example, since declaring with const - instead of var or let - implies leaving the variable 'port' untouched, will it have any effect?

Comment: You can read the following question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40070631/v8-javascript-performance-implications-of-const-let-and-var)

Comment: Declaring a variable will invoke a lookup. No matter how fast it is, it will take some extra time. So its slower. *it improves performance of loops*, checking `i< array.length` will be slower than `i<length`. So yes it does add a little but in some cases. But improving algo and reducing number of iterations will always give better result. You should find a balance between readable, maintainable and performant code

Comment: @Rajesh https://stackoverflow.com/a/17995000/438992

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, simply by storing a value in a variable does not increase the performance, in fact, there will be a slightly reduced performance since additional memory allocation and fetching happens.

However, storing the result of a computation in a variable and using the variable instead of re-computing it every time the values are required improves the performance.

Converting `app.listen(3000)` into below format does not have any performance benefit.

```
const port = 3000;
app.listen(port)
```

However, if the `port` values require some computation like,

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
```

then storing the result in a variable and using that values every time port number is required will have a performance benefit compared to computing it every time.

(In your example, since the `port` value is used only once, there is no point in storing the result in a variable.)

> I heard, for example, it improves performance of loops. 
>   Again, you have a performance benefit only if the value stored in the variable requires some form of computation.

```
const array = [1,2,3];
const length = array.length;
for (let i =0 ;i<length; i++) {
  console.log(array[i]);
}
```

The above example has performance benefits compared to the one below.

```
const array = [1,2,3];
for (let i =0 ;i<array.length; i++) {
  console.log(array[i]);
}
```

In this example, in every iteration of the loop, the length of the array has to be calculated which is not necessary since the array does not change.

> And off-topic: isn't app.listen() function kinda a loop? Or does it use an inbuilt loop?

No, `app.listen()` is not a loop. It is an event listener. Internally the node event loop handles such I/O operations. You can read more about the event loop [here](https://nodejs.org/de/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/).